# Why a request isn't caught by the controller but appears in Wireshark?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wireshark

In my Controller class I've got following mapping:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/join/{roomId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

I've put a breakpoint in the first line and sometimes when I send a request it isn't caught by debugger and the response is `null`.

I've captured the traffic using Wireshark and the requests appear there. 
On client side I've looped the request so when the null comes I repeat it.

Here's the log from Wireshark. Third request succeeded:

[image: Wireshark packets]

PS. I know there are two backslashes but it doesn't matter.

I can provide further details if required.

Edit:
Class skeleton:

```
@Controller
public class RoomController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoomController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/join/{roomId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void joinToRoom(@PathVariable("roomId") String roomId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {      
        logger.info("joinToRoom");  
        ...
    }

}
```

Edit2: Without the extra slash:
[image]

Comment: are you sure the extra slash does not matter?

Comment: yes, you can see that request 150 has its response in 154 so why not the previous ones?

Comment: I see, if the failure is intermittent, there's something else at play (maybe?) - is there any clusters, load balancers or anything like that?

Comment: Let us see the full class skeleton.......